# On a UNIX system that is quickly running out of space (MacOS, GNU/Linux) - what is fastest way to find which process and FS path is responsible?

Tags: linux, macos, filesystems

This is a scenario that I experienced both on MacOS and GNU/Linux - a rogue process starts eating disk space. Very fast. You can see with `iostat` massive writes, with `df -h` that percents of free space are lower and lower, in few minutes 100% of disk will be full.

What's the quickest way to figure out which process is doing that and where on the disk is the growing blob of used disk space?

On GNU/Linux I would probably go for `lsof` but that usually takes a lot of time to process, maybe it would be faster to traverse /proc and look for `fd` folders for each process and check which one is growing fastest? Is there any good userspace tool for this?

How about MacOS is there anything that can be done?

Comment: `du -sm -d 1 /` you will see which folder is the most important resources eating one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Keep Activity Monitor open, on a separate Space, so you can quickly flick over to it if something goes runaway.

Use the Disk tab set to sort by Bytes Written. In the View menu set to 'All Processes'.

If something is runaway, you'll quickly see it rising to the top of that page. As the monitoring was already running, there's nothing to launch that you have to wait to finish processing.

This won't tell you where, but it should tell you what, and you can kill it right from that page if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If `du` does not see this used space but `df` does, then
you are dealing with deleted files.
Deleted files only disappear after the owner process is stopped,
but remain in use until that happens.

`lsof` is the best tool for finding the culprit process,
using the following command:

```
sudo lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'
```

You may embed this command for killing the process:

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof | grep deleted | cut -d " " -f4)
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366626/17660)

Comment: `du` of course would see these files, but problem is I have no idea where on the whole filesystem these files are. That's the point of my question. How do you find files that are growing fast anywhere on the filesystem?

Comment: Perhaps `iotop` with the `-a` flag to show accumulated I/O instead of bandwidth. Or in [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) to hit `d` for disk details.

Comment: Deleted files should disappear once the file descriptor is closed or they are unlink()ed, no?

Comment: When deleting a large file or files, the file is deleted successfully but the size of the filesystem only reflects the change when the process terminates. See [example link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316).